# How to parse a string using regex or another technique?

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse the id from the following string:

```
 https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/24k-magic/id1161503945?i=1161504024&uo=2
```

I need to only return the following:

```
id1161503945
```

The string always begins with https://itunes.apple.com/ and ends with ?i=#####&uo=2

I tried string and replace with wildcards but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use this below regex. It is working. I have use preg_replace function.

```
$data = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/24k-magic/id1161503945?i=1161504024&uo=2';
echo preg_replace("/(.*)\/(\w+)\?(.*)/","$2",$data);
```

Output is

id1161503945

Or You can use

```
 preg_match("/(\/)(\w+)(\?)/",$data,$m);

 echo $m[2];
```

Same output.

Hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

If it's really always the last element (before query params) in the url, then you can use this simple regex:

`'/id[^?]+/'`

CAUTION: as pointed by @xhienne, this works *only* if you're sure that another `id` string doesn't appear anywhere before the searched part.
If it may happen, rather use:

`'/id[\d]+/'`

This way, it's safe with respect to a previous `id` string, but the searched `id` must be followed by digits only.

Comment: I tested it and it returns "1" withought the quotes

Comment: @JohnDenver Seems that you take the "returned" value from preg_match! Assuming $url is your tested url, write `preg_match('/id[^?]+/', $url, $match);`. Then the expected result is in `$match[0]`.

Comment: That would rather be `'/id[0-9]+/'`, else you are likely to match the album name, like in https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id-look-good-on-you-single/id1094054642

Comment: @xhienne I don't understand what you mean.  `[^?]+` accepts any id (even if not only digits), and stops before query params, if any.

Comment: @cFreed See the URL I gave. Your regex would yield `id-look-good-on-you-single/id1094054642`. An iTunes id always ends with digits (after "id"). The id is the last part of the URL, after `/` and before a possible query. These conditions have to be included in the regex (mine is incomplete in this regard)

Comment: @xhienne Oh, yes now I understand. Anyway the OP has accepted another answer so it doesn't matter any longer :)

Comment: @cFreed A question may have several good answers. You can make yours as good as the other one.

Comment: @xhienne Uh... you're perfectionist :) But you're right. So that's done.